# Angular CDK Layout - How to dynamically update CSS in response to screen-size changes?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-changedetection

I'm setting up a code that detects the present breakpoint and updates the class accordingly.

I've managed to get it working based on the initial value, but when the window size enlarges/shrinks, the Html class does not detect the changes without me refreshing the page.

I think the code would look something like this?

**Example Component:**

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnChanges {
    htmlStyles: string;
    constructor(
        private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver
    ) { }
    ngOnChanges(): void {
        // Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
        // Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.

        this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset, Breakpoints.Medium, Breakpoints.Small])
            .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
                if (state.matches) {
                    this.htmlStyles = 'dummy1';
                } else {
                    this.htmlStyles = 'dummy2';
                }
            });
    }
}
```

**Example Html:**

```
<div [ngClass]="htmlStyles" style='max-width: fit-content'>
    test
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `this.breakpointObserver.observe` should be initialized in `ngOnInit`:

```js
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'


@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  htmlStyles: string;

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Small])
      .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
        if (state.matches) {
          this.htmlStyles = 'dummy1';
        } else {
          this.htmlStyles = 'dummy2';
        }
      });
  }
}
```

See [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtkqw7).

Comment: Thanks for this, the example was helpful!